# How to upload an image in React without a server?

Tags: reactjs, image-upload

I have a bootstrap input field for images in my react app. When I upload an image through it, I want to get a public URL of that image so that I could reuse it in another part of the app.

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Product Image</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
</div>
```

I've seen people connect to an API like google drive and upload the image to get a kind of shareable link. Is there a way to do that on the client side?

Thanks for the notice :)

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying that you are OK with uploading to a 3rd party system (i.e. Google Drive, imgur, etc)?  Even then, you would have to have some way to coordinate sharing a reference to that hosted file, which again means databases and servers.

Comment: I'm new on this topic, so any quick way to get started would do.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to have a publicly accessible system to serve images.  That means a server.

I can't think of any way to come close this without involving *some* kind of 3rd party system/server.  Even if you were to do something as involved as a peer-to-peer system of sharing images over WebRTC, you would still need a signalling server to make the initial connection between clients.

---

The way that apps work with content sharing in a generalized manner is that a user will upload an image on the front-end to some content repository.  That could be your own content repository or some 3rd party site like imgur, Google Drive, etc.  Once it's uploaded, a link to that publicly available content is stored by your own application and then used in some way such as being shown on a user's content board or profile.

For example, Stack Overflow itself integrates with [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) so that whenever you need to upload an image to go along with your question/answer it is associated to your post and hosted out of imgur.  SO still has to plumb all associated stuff like knowing who uploaded what and what question it's related to where to put it in the post.

Providing a complete solution would be too broad, but a possible, birds eye view could be something like:

1. Serve front-end however
2. Serve back-end that has content accepting mechanism (maybe something like [Strapi](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#upload-files)
3. Hook the front-end up to use the content accepting endpoint
4. Have a main page that just shows all the images that have ever been uploaded

Bear in mind, that it's rather complicated to do all this and curating content is also a ***HUGE*** endeavor whenever you have to deal with people uploading illicit content.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give a reference for doing the above with third-party software?

Comment: Right, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using google drive as a backend is one solution, [their API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) is a good starting point. In general IMHO you want to explore the "serverless" concept. Amazon has a lot of services available in this area.

Comment: Please give a reference on how to set that up too.

Comment: @EthanLal Start with their docs, or search the web for tutorials.